# add to array if it isn't there already

Tags: php

How do I add elements to an array only if they aren't in there already? I have the following:

```
$a=array();
// organize the array
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $key=>$value){
        if($key=='key'){
        $a[]=$value;
        }
    }
}

print_r($a);
```

// Output

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 1
[4] => 2
[5] => 3
[6] => 4
[7] => 5
[8] => 6

)
```

Instead, I want $a to consist of the unique values. (I know I can use array_unique to get the desired results but I just want to know)

Comment: For those searching for Laravel solution, the `Arr::wrap()` is the answer, see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-wrap).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You'd have to check each value against [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array):

```
$a=array();
// organize the array by cusip
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $key=>$value){
        if(!in_array($value, $a)){
        $a[]=$value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the volume of the input data increases, `in_array()` will experience increasingly worse performance.

Answer (score 188):

You should use the PHP function `in_array` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
if (!in_array($value, $array))
{
    $array[] = $value; 
}
```

This is what the documentation says about `in_array`:

> *Returns **TRUE** if needle is found in the array, **FALSE** otherwise.*

Comment: This is by far the easiest way of doing this

Answer (score 30):

Since you seem to only have [scalar values](http://php.net/language.types.intro) an PHP’s array is rather a hash map, you could use the value as key to avoid duplicates and associate the `$k` keys to them to be able to get the original values:

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v){
    if (isset($v['key'])) {
        $keys[$value] = $k;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to iterate it to get the original values:

```
$unique = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $unique[] = $array[$key]['key'];
}
```

This is probably not the most obvious and most comprehensive approach but it is very efficient as it is in O(*n*).

Using [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) instead like others suggested is probably more intuitive. But you would end up with an algorithm in O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) (`in_array` is in O(*n*)) that is not applicable. Even pushing all values in the array and using [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) on it would be better than `in_array` (`array_unique` sorts the values in O(*n*·log *n*) and then removes successive duplicates).

Comment: This is the solution I prefer most of the time. array keys rock in php.

Comment: There's a suggested edit by @xmedeko that suggests that the cost is `O(n logn)` not `O(n)` because of "the cost on PHP hashing", could both of you reach an agreement here? :-)

Comment: IMHO array_unique preserves the original order values, while your solutions doesn't.

Answer (score 17):

```
if (!in_array(...))  
  array_push(..)
```

Answer (score 10):

Easy to write, but not the most effective one:

```
$array = array_unique(array_merge($array, $array_to_append));
```

This one is probably faster:

```
$array = array_merge($array, array_diff($array_to_append, $array));
```

Comment: Great solution, Thanks

Comment: According to my IDE (PHPStorm, since I have not done performance comparison) the first one is faster. PHPStorm gave me a "resource intensive operation used in loop" warning when using array_merge + array_diff.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (!in_array($value, $a))
  $a[]=$value;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding as key instead of value:

Adding an entry

```
function addEntry($entry) {
    $this->entries[$entry] = true;
}
```

Getting all entries

```
function getEntries() {
    return array_keys($this->enties);
}
```

Comment: This is how Java implements HashSets (with an embedded HashMap and a value, I think consisting of a static `new Object()`)

Answer (score 4):

If you're okay with using **shorthands** in your code (instead of writing explicit `if` blocks, like some **coding standards** recommend), you can further simplify [Marius Schulz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083581/4730881) with this one-liner:

```
in_array ($value, $array) || $array [] = $value;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the ordering of the keys, you could do the following:

```
$array = YOUR_ARRAY
$unique = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $unique[$a] = $a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there are a ton of ways to accomplish the desired results and so many people provided `!in_array()` as an answer, and the OP already mentions the use of `array_unique`, I would like to provide a couple alternatives.

Using `array_diff` (php >= 4.0.1 || 5) you can filter out only the new array values that don't exist. Alternatively you can also compare the keys and values with `array_diff_assoc`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```php
$currentValues = array(1, 2);
$newValues = array(1, 3, 1, 4, 2);
var_dump(array_diff($newValues, $currentValues));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

http://ideone.com/SWO3D1

Another method is using `array_flip` to assign the values as keys and compare them using `isset`, which will perform much faster than `in_array` with large datasets. Again this filters out just the new values that do not already exist in the current values.

```php
$currentValues = [1, 2];
$newValues = [1, 3, 1, 4, 2];
$a = array();
$checkValues = array_flip($currentValues);
foreach ($newValues as $v) {
    if (!isset($checkValues[$v])) {
        $a[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

http://ideone.com/cyRyzN

With either method you can then use `array_merge` to append the unique new values to your current values.

1. http://ideone.com/JCakmR
2. http://ideone.com/bwTz2u

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using "in_array":

```
function insert_value($value, &$_arr) {
    if (!in_array($value, $_arr)) {
        $_arr[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Gumbo's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083605/468793), making the code work:

```
$array = array('111111','222222','3333333','4444','5555', 
'AAAAAA', 'BBBBBB', 'CCC', 'DDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEE', 'FFFFFF', 'GGG',
'AAAAAA', 'BBBBBB', 'CCC', 'DDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEE', 'FFFFFF', 'GGG',
'222222', 
'666666', '777777', 'HHHH');

print_r($array);

$keys= array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v){
    if (isset($v['value'])) {
        $keys[$v] = $k;
    }
}
$unique = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $unique[] = $array[$key];
}
print "<br><br>";
print_r($unique);
```

Gives this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111111
    [1] => 222222
    [2] => 3333333
    [3] => 4444
    [4] => 5555
    [5] => AAAAAA
    [6] => BBBBBB
    [7] => CCC
    [8] => DDDDDDD
    [9] => EEEEEEEE
    [10] => FFFFFF
    [11] => GGG
    [12] => AAAAAA
    [13] => BBBBBB
    [14] => CCC
    [15] => DDDDDDD
    [16] => EEEEEEEE
    [17] => FFFFFF
    [18] => GGG
    [19] => 222222
    [20] => 666666
    [21] => 777777
    [22] => HHHH
)

Array
(
    [0] => 111111
    [1] => 222222
    [2] => 3333333
    [3] => 4444
    [4] => 5555
    [5] => AAAAAA
    [6] => BBBBBB
    [7] => CCC
    [8] => DDDDDDD
    [9] => EEEEEEEE
    [10] => FFFFFF
    [11] => GGG
    [12] => 666666
    [13] => 777777
    [14] => HHHH
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `array_flip()` it could look like this:

```
$flipped = array_flip($opts);
$flipped[$newValue] = 1;
$opts = array_keys($flipped);
```

With `array_unique()` - like this:

```
$opts[] = $newValue;
$opts = array_values(array_unique($opts));
```

Notice that `array_values(...)` — you need it if you're exporting array to JavaScript in JSON form. `array_unique()` alone would simply unset duplicate keys, without rebuilding the remaining elements'. So, after converting to JSON this would produce object, instead of array.

```
>>> json_encode(array_unique(['a','b','b','c']))
=> "{"0":"a","1":"b","3":"c"}"

>>> json_encode(array_values(array_unique(['a','b','b','c'])))
=> "["a","b","c"]"
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this code, I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

```
$input = Array(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6);
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```