# Add missing values to second array

Tags: php

I have two arrays, the first is below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21-02
    [1] => 21-01
    [2] => 21-03
    [3] => 21-04
    [4] => 21-05
    [5] => 21-06
    [6] => 21-07
    [7] => 21-08
    [8] => 21-09
)
```

I need to check what values don't exist in this second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21-01
    [1] => 21-02
)
```

If they don't exist in the second array then I need to add them. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show the resulting array you need at the end from the above 2 array in the example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add to array if it isn't there already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083567/add-to-array-if-it-isnt-there-already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

```
$valuesThatAreNotInArray2 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

After you have the differences between the first array and the second array you can merge the differences with the second array.

```
$array2 = array_merge($array2, $valuesThatAreNotInArray2);
```